# Trying to use a front matter element in a liquid {% for %} loop

Tags: html, templates, liquid, eleventy

I have the following front matter in an html file:

```
---
layout: default
title: Fausto Bellino Tasca | Montecito
permalink: "/montecito.html"
imageSet: "montecito"
---
```

In the body of the html, I have the following:

```
{% for image-info in galleries.{{ imageSet }} %}
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="/images/{{ imageSet }}/{{ image-info.filename }}" alt="{{ image-info.caption }}">
    <div class="main-slider-caption">
      {{ image-info.caption }}
    </div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The {{ imageSet }} within the img tag works fine, but when I attempt to use it in the for loop, eleventy throws an error with the following:

```
`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> Having trouble compiling template ./src/montecito.html

`TemplateContentCompileError` was thrown
> illegal tag: {% for image-info in galleries.{{ imageSet }} %}, file:./src/montecito.html, line:11

`ParseError` was thrown
> illegal tag: {% for image-info in galleries.{{ imageSet }} %}

`AssertionError` was thrown:
    AssertionError: illegal tag: {% for image-info in galleries.{{ imageSet }} %}
```

There is additional error info, noting the liquid js files that threw the error.

When I simply replace the {{ imageSet }} with the text itself, i.e., 'montecito' in this case, it works fine.

Any thoughts would be welcome as I've got a lot of pages that will look like this and I'd like to make a shortcode out of this look and pass in the front matter item.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer. The correct syntax in this context is galleries[imageSet] instead of galleries.{{ imageSet }}.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. The correct syntax in this context is galleries[imageSet] instead of galleries.{{ imageSet }}.